# Why do I need to start Xcode debugger to get the Crashlytics report?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have an iOS app where I want to have Crashlytics.

I did the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started).

It is working fine, but to get something in the Firebase console, I need to:

- Start the application without debugger
- Make the app crash
- Start the app with the Xcode debugger

Without the debugger, I don't get anything at Firebase end. Why?

The script info that I have:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

And the input files are:

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it seems the reason was I was not crashing the application 'far enough' in my app.

I tried somewhere else and the reporting was done properly.